# Are XHDPI images meant for use with retina displays in Android?

Tags: android

Should we use XHDPI images for retina display in Android? If not, where should I place images/assets for the Samsung Galaxy S3.

**Update:**
I found a useful artical:
[List of Android Devices with pixel density buckets](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S3 got a density of around 309 pixels per inch. From the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) on supporting multiple screen densities:

> xhdpi: Resources for extra high-density (xhdpi) screens (~320dpi)

I think we can conclude that assets for the S3 should be placed in the **xhdpi** folder.